# nonclustered index on join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, non-clustered-index

I have been wondering if having nonclustered index on the join would improve performance?? like

```
INNER JOIN FaceList fl ON fl.FaceListID = flf.FaceListID
```

in above join can I get performance benefit when I have nonclustered index on FaceListID since its unique combination and return a definite result

Any link or suggestion is appreciated

Comment: **YES!** most definitely. Putting a nonclustered index on any foreign key columns is an accepted best practice. It helps because thanks  to the index, the values in that column are presented to the query optimizer in a sorted way - so it can use more efficient merging operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely need to put non-clustered index on foreign-key column:

Read more:

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/11/t-sql-queries/benefits-indexing-foreign-keys